# How to fetch data from servlet using ajax?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

First of all, this might seem like a duplicate but I assure you I have tried many questions and still hasn't got a proper answer. So I'm asking this here.

I have an HTML form from which I would like to submit a query to a servlet and show the results in a different division.

My HTML code essentially consists of the following:

```
<form>
    <input name="query" id="query" placeholder="Query">
    <button id="searchDoc">Search</button>
</form>
<div id="search-results"></div>
```

I have the following jQuery in order to handle the ajax call.

```
$('#searchDoc').click(function() {
      var q = $('#query').val();
      $.ajax({
         url: "QueryServlet",
         data: {query:q},
         success: function(data) {
             alert("data: " + data);
             $('#search-results').html(data);
         }
      });
  });
```

My `QueryServlet` is:

```
@WebServlet("/QueryServlet")
public class QueryServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public QueryServlet() {
    super();
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String query = request.getParameter("query");
    QueryUtil qu = new QueryUtil();
    String mySqlQuery = qu.buildMySQLSearchQuery(query);
    System.out.println(mySqlQuery);
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        con = new DbConnection().getConnection();
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(mySqlQuery);
        if(rs != null) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            while(rs.next()) {
                out.println("<a href=\"DownloadServlet?docId=" + rs.getInt("id") + "\">" + rs.getString("fileName") + "</a>");
            }
        } else {
            // TODO add keywords to database
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}

}
```

Even when I submit a valid query, the div does not get loaded up with the data from the servlet. The data reaches the servlet and gets displayed in the console, but I am unable to retrieve that data from the script.

Comment: Do you get the alert? You should open up the Developer Tools if you are using Chrome, where you can see what's been actually transfered between the browser and your server.

Comment: I tried debugging with firebug. The breakpoint at the alert is never reached.

Comment: I think your issue is the `url` parameter in your jQuery ajax. See if this works: `url: "/QueryServlet"`.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi The query does reach the servlet because I do get the console message printed at the server side.

Comment: use this button     `<input type="button" id="searchDoc" value="search"/>`

I think other button loads the page again

Comment: @shyam what you just said does not make sense. Does it call the servlet at least?

Comment: If you get alert also try to set using innerHTML

Comment: You're only providing a success handler. Provide a failure handler as well, it's obviously not getting a successful result back from the server.

Comment: Use Firebug to check if your query is successful or not, you can also open the query in a separate tab and see what's shown.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi indeed that did not make any sense. But the page got reloaded removing any updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<button>` tag is equivalent to an `<input type="submit"/>`. If you in your `form` tag don't declare any `action` attribute, the standard action causes that the page is reloaded. This causes that, although the returned data are inserted in `#search-results` div, you'll never be able to see them, because the page is immediately reloaded.

You should deactivate the default "Submit" button this way:

```
$('#searchDoc').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      [....]
  });
```

This should fix your problem!

Answer (score 0):

the issue seems related to  context path, your path should look like this if servlet is not in context root   :-

```
<host> / <context path>/ <servlet>
```

Thanks :)